# Code works for image but not for other files in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, file-upload, codeigniter-3, sql-update

I successfully uploaded the image into the folder and its name to the database but same code does not upload the file in the folder but uploads the name in the database.Following is my code to upload the audio file to my folder musics.

**Controller Function**

```
public function add_audio(){

        $config['upload_path'] = './musics/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3';
        $config['max_size'] = '100000000000000';

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        chmod('musics/', 0777);
        $this->upload->do_upload('output');

        $data['audio'] = $_FILES['output']['name'];
        $this->load->model('main');
        $query = $this->main->insert('audio',$data);            

        if($query = TRUE){

            $this->load->view('admin/success');
        }
        else{

            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }   //end else
    }   //end function
```

Comment: if($query = TRUE)

should be == not single equal sign..you are comparing it and not assigning value to $query. Use ==

Comment: try removing `'output'` from `$this->upload->do_upload('output');`

Comment: i have done == and remove 'output'...  it but still file doesnot get the folder....only its name is uploaded to the database....i don't know what is wrong and it is frustrating me......@LeeBalino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `'output'` from `$this->upload->do_upload('output');`

and try to replace your part of your code with this:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();    
    //line of codes that displays if there are errors
}
else
{
    $data['audio'] = $_FILES['output']['name'];

    $this->load->model('main');
    $query = $this->main->insert('audio',$data);

    if($query == TRUE){
        $this->load->view('admin/success');
    }
}
```

Comment: i replace my code with your code but it shows the blank page ....nothing displayed @lee balino

Comment: try `printr($data['error'])`. let's see what is the error

Comment: it says you didn't select the file to upload...@Lee Balino

Comment: i found the what was the problem it was in the php.ini file it was not set to the maxmimum upload limit...any way thanks for your reply...

Comment: @sudeepacharya NP bro

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you have specified

```
if($query = TRUE){
    $this->load->view('admin/success');
}
```

Since it's a comparison and not as assignment this should be corrected as

```
if($query == TRUE){
    $this->load->view('admin/success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it by other file formats whether you are getting or not by:

`print_r($_FILES);`

and you are using `=` instead of `==` in if condition.

try this:

```
    if($query = TRUE){

             $this->load->view('admin/success');
    }
```